# CSS Only Fixed Table Headers with out Table header with only td and tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to create a sticky table header with out table header with only the first tr will have the sticky head , can any one help with only CSS?
Please use this fiddle to fix , not the below table 
https://jsfiddle.net/x243jqbg/

```
<table class="table"> 
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1</td>
      <td>row 2</td>
      <td>row 3</td>
      <td>row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Like Below https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/PrJdxb

Comment: I have checked your codepen.io. You want the first th that is red colour to sticky till end of the table right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `table` as `position: relative`

```
table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

Then set the first row as `position: sticky`

```
tr:first-child td {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Check out my codepen: https://codepen.io/kenneth-bolico/pen/QWLoNry

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr:first-child` selector to target the first row. And then style it accordingly.

```css
.table {
  position: relative;
}

tr:first-child td {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1</td>
      <td>row 2</td>
      <td>row 3</td>
      <td>row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```